# why git-svn should search aggressively for old history?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

Something strange happened when I ran git svn clone -s, though the following information tells  us to not be alarmed, I wonder why that is kind of svn error?

Why this path does not exist, is it deleted by others?

If yes, why git svn should search  aggressively for old history?

```
Initializing parent: refs/remotes/tags/sequentialInformationalBottleneckClusterer-1.0.1@8400
W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem has no item: File not found: revision 101, path '/trunk/packages/internal/sequentialInformationalBottleneckClusterer'
W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is just searching aggressively for old history.
This may take a while on large repositories
Checked through r1501
```

Comment: Great question.  Good opportunity to dispel FUD.

Answer (score 10):

This was a fun one. Do not be alarmed.

The `W:` signifies "warning", and all this warning tells you is that `/trunk/packages/internal/sequentialInformationalBottleneckClusterer` doesn't have a revision between r0 and r100 in your SVN repository. The warning was introduced in early 2008.

```
commit eee8a1742bf51df33f0f6004774035f57253f944
Author: Eric Wong <normalperson@yhbt.net>
Date:   Mon Jan 7 02:40:40 2008 -0800

    git-svn: clarify the "Ignoring error from SVN" piece

    I've heard of several users puzzled by this, and it sometimes it
    appears as if git-svn is doing nothing on slower connections and
    larger repositories.

    Signed-off-by: Eric Wong <normalperson@yhbt.net>
    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
```

You can read the [original thread here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/git-version-control/CZCX76DzWPY/4GYhb_KEmB0J) if you're interested. In the meantime, just ignore the warning. The subroutine in question, [`skip_unknown_revs`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/perl/Git/SVN/Ra.pm#L595-625) (warning, this link will age if the file in github changes) would kill the process if it caught an unexpected error.